# Create a pretty url without touching the file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

Is it possible to create a pretty url without having to touch the file itself? For example:

```
http://sawebdev01/company/news-events/press-releases/press-release/?pr=168#.Uajh_kCyBSK
```

And convert it to:

```
http://sawebdev01/company/news-events/press-releases/pr/168
```

I tried this, and it does not seem to work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /company/news-events/press-releases/press-release/?pr=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .*             /company/news-events/press-releases/press-release/pr/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(/company/news-events/press-releases)/press-release/\?pr=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/pr/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(company/news-events/press-releases)/pr/([^/]+)/?$ /$1/press-release?pr=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```